# Recursive list connat read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: angular, ng-template

I'm doing a recursive list and I can't get my entire list.

```
<ul>
  <ng-container
    *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveListTmpl; context:{ list: famillies }"
  ></ng-container>
</ul>

<ng-template #recursiveListTmpl let-list="list">
  <li *ngFor="let item of list">
    {{ item.libelle }}
    <ul *ngIf="item.famillies2.length != 0">
      <ng-container
        *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveListTmpl; context:{ list: item.famillies2 }"
      ></ng-container>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ng-template>
```

TS

```
 getFamillies() {
    this.service
      .getFamillies()
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.famillies = data;

      });
  }
```

The result displays the first familly and its first child then the famillies2 is undefined, I'm supposed to get 2 children in the first familly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it's recursive the last child might not have the `famillies2` property. In other words you must provide a condition to stop the recursive call.

**Option 1: [Short circuit (`&&`)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND#short-circuit_evaluation)**

```html
<ul *ngIf="item && item.famillies2 && item.famillies2.length && item.famillies2.length != 0">
  <ng-container
    *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveListTmpl; context:{ list: item.famillies2 }"
  ></ng-container>
</ul>
```

**Option 2: Safe navigation operator (`?.`)**

```html
<ul *ngIf="item?.famillies2?.length != 0">
  <ng-container
    *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveListTmpl; context:{ list: item.famillies2 }"
  ></ng-container>
</ul>
```